# MIPS program to find the sum and square sum of 10 integers

Tags: assembly

I wrote a program (hard-code) in MIPS that gets an array of 10 integers and calculates the sum and the square sum of them. 
The array is `{23,-2,45,67,89,12,-100,0,120,6}`

```
.data
array: .word 23,-2,45,67,89,12,-100,0,120,6 # array = {23,-2,45,67,89,12,-100,0,120,6}
length: .word 10 # the length of the array is 10
sum: .word 0 # the sum of the integers (in array) is 0
squareSum: .word 0 # the square sum of the integers (in array) is 0
sumMessage: .asciiz "The sum of the array(sign) is: "
squareMessage: .asciiz "The sum of the squares(sign) is: "
newLine: .asciiz "\n"

# Algorithm being implemented to sum an array
# sum = 0 (use $t0 for sum)
# squarSum = 0 (use %t5 for squarSum)
# for i = 0 to length-1 do (use $t1 for i)
# sum = sum + array[i] (use $t2 for length-1)
# squareSum = squareSum + array[i]*array[i]
# end for (use $t3 for base addr. of array)

.text
main:

li $t0, 0 # load immediate 0 in register $t0 (sum)
li $t5, 0 # load immediate 0 in register $t0 (squarSum)
la $t3, array # load base addr. of array into $t3
lw $t2, length # load length in register $t2
addi $t2, $t2, -1 # $t2 = length - 1
li $t1, 0 # initialize i in $t1 to 0

loop:

bgt $t1, $t2, exit # exit loop when i > (length-1)
mul $t4, $t1, 4 # multiple i by 4 to get offset within array
add $t4, $t3, $t4 # add base addr. of array to $t4 to get addr. of array[i]
lw $t4, 0($t4) # load value of array[i] from memory into $t4
add $t0, $t0, $t4 # update sum
mul $t6, $t4, $t4 # temp register %t6 
add $t5,$t5,$t6 # update squareSum
addi $t1, $t1, 1 # increment i
j loop

exit:

# print sum message
li $v0, 4
la $a0, sumMessage
syscall 
# print value of sum
li $v0, 1
addi $a0,$t0,0
syscall
# print new line
li $v0, 4
la $a0, newLine
syscall 
# print square sum message 
li $v0, 4
la $a0, squareMessage
syscall 
# print value of squareSum
li $v0, 1
addi $a0,$t5,0
syscall
```

Is this a good implementation?  How can I improve it?

Answer (score 4):

Your program is correct. I ran it and verified the results against a C program. So, it works and the code is pretty good, too.

You did a good job of commenting. Especially, the top block where you detail the algorithm and the intended register usage. And, putting a sidebar comment on each asm line is also very good.

But, you also wanted to know how to improve it. So, a few things ...

I realize you're just starting out, but sidebar comments should talk about *intent*. That is, what are we doing with the algorithm, instead of just rehashing the mechanics of the asm instruction.

I tightened things up a bit. Instead of what you did (in C/pseudo code):

```
int i;
int val;

for (i = 0;  i <= (length - 1);  ++i) {
    val = array[i];
    ...
}
```

I changed this into:

```
int *arrptr;
int *arrend;
int val;

arrptr = array;
arrend = &array[length];
for (;  arrptr < arrend;  ++arrptr) {
    val = *arrptr;
    ...
}
```

I was also able to eliminate a few extra instructions by changing some of the registers being used and eliminate a extra branch instruction in the loop

---

Anyway, here's the cleaned up/improved code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .data
array:      .word       23,-2,45,67,89,12,-100,0,120,6
arrend:

sumMessage: .asciiz     "The sum of the array(sign) is: "
squareMessage:  .asciiz "The sum of the squares(sign) is: "
newLine:    .asciiz     "\n"

    # array = {23,-2,45,67,89,12,-100,0,120,6}
    # the sum of the integers (in array) is 0
    # the square sum of the integers (in array) is 0

    # Algorithm being implemented to sum an array
    # sum = 0 (use $t0 for sum)
    # squarSum = 0 (use %t5 for squarSum)
    # for i = 0 to length-1 do (use $t1 for i)
    # sum = sum + array[i] (use $t2 for length-1)
    # squareSum = squareSum + array[i]*array[i]
    # end for (use $t3 for base addr. of array)

    # registers:
    #   t0 -- sum
    #   t5 -- squarSum
    #
    #   t3 -- pointer to current array element (e.g. arrptr)
    #   t2 -- pointer to end of array
    #
    #   t4 -- current value fetched from array
    #   t6 -- temp to hold squared value

    .text

main:
    li      $t0,0                   # sum = 0
    li      $t5,0                   # squarSum = 0

    la      $t3,array               # load base addr. of array
    la      $t2,arrend              # load address of array end
    j       test

loop:
    lw      $t4,0($t3)              # load array[i]
    addi    $t3,$t3,4               # increment array pointer

    add     $t0,$t0,$t4             # update sum
    mul     $t6,$t4,$t4             # get val * val
    add     $t5,$t5,$t6             # update squareSum

test:
    blt     $t3,$t2,loop            # more to do? if yes, loop

    # print sum message
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,sumMessage
    syscall

    # print value of sum
    li      $v0,1
    addi    $a0,$t0,0
    syscall

    # print new line
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,newLine
    syscall

    # print square sum message
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,squareMessage
    syscall

    # print value of squareSum
    li      $v0,1
    addi    $a0,$t5,0
    syscall

    li      $v0,10
    syscall
```

---

If you'd like to see some further tips on writing good/clean asm, based on my own personal experience, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538325/mips-linked-list/36560575#36560575

---

**UPDATE:**

> I didn't understand the "arrend" part. how does it know that `$t2 = 10`?

`$t2` no longer has a count. It was repurposed to hold the address of the array's end address. The two loops are fundamentally different in how they iterate and terminate. This was evidenced in the C samples given above.

Your code used `$t2` to hold the *length/count* of `array`, which was `10`. Your loop was using an index variable [contained in `$t1`] to iterate through the array and stopping when the index value hit the count. It was incrementing the index value by `1` on each loop iteration.

In the modified code, `$t2` holds the *address* of `arrend`. This is "one beyond" the last element of `array`. The loop stops when the *pointer* to the current array value [in `$t3`] hits/equals the array end. It was incrementing the pointer by `4` on each iteration.

In strictest terms, the loop doesn't use or care about the count. What it cares about is: "If I know the address of the array end, has my current address/pointer gone past it?"

Just for completeness, let's go the other way. In `mars`, `array` has address `0x10010000` and `arrend` has address `0x10010028`. If we subtract the addresses, `arrend` is *offset* from `array` by `0x28` bytes, which is `40` (decimal). If we divide this by 4 [the size of a word] to get the count, we have `10`

Comment: I didn't understand the "arrend" part. how does it know that `$t2 = 10`?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code for a similar problem that is quite precise and can be implemented with ease. Here I take an input *n* which prints the sum of product for consecutive integers starting from 1, i.e. array size *n*.
In your case, what can be done is that you take the length and array both as the input and run the loop *array length* times and the loop instead of running for *n* should read the elements of the array, store them then store their square, increment the address by 4 to read each index and keep adding the squares to the previously updated sum. Your code however is pretty much accurate and seems to give an accurate result.

```
# SUM OF SQUARES
    .data
#initialisation prompt to ask the user for their input
n: .asciiz "enter n: "

.text
.globl main
main:
#declaring i and initiating its value to 0
li $t0, 0  

#printing prompt to ask from user
li $v0,4
la $a0, n
syscall

#inputting value from console
li $v0,5
syscall 
#moving to temporary variable t1
move $t1, $v0

#initialising sum as 0, stored as t3
li $t3 0
#Function acting as a loop
function:
#condition to end the loop and jump to print function
#while(t0!=t1)
    beq $t0 $t1 print
#incrementation of loop variable (t0)
    addi $t0 $t0 1
#calculating square of t0 and storing it in t4
    mul $t4 $t0 $t0
#adding the current squared to previous sum and again storing it in sum(t3)
    add $t3 $t3 $t4 
#loop to this function again
    j function

#procedure to print the sum(t3)
print:
move $a0 $t3
li $v0 1
syscall

#exit procedure
end:
li $v0 10
syscall
```

Comment: (You don't need to multiply to generate squares of consecutive integers.) *Accuracy* is a non-issue with integral arithmetic, and I find it difficult to apply to program source code. That one sentence was all referring to the code presented for review that I could discern: You seem to be asking a new question?! Then don't use "the *Your Answer* editor", but "the *Ask Question* button".